# Visual Studio 2012 C#: Remove ALL *Checked Items in a CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, checkedlistbox, items, removeall

I am an EXTREME newbie to both C# and more importantly, Visual Studio 2012, so sorry if this seems like an easy question. So I am making a To Do List application as my first little project with VS2012. I have a CheckedListBox named 'checkedListBox1' and a button for deleting the marked (or checked) items all at once named 'markButton'. I have wrote the following code but as you can see in my comment, it does something weird: deletes every other checked item from the collection of checked items I have.

---

```
private void markButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // create a collection of the checked items in the to do list
    // then remove each of them.
    // **** ERROR: It deletes every other checked item 
    // so it deletes indeces 0..2..4..6... each time.
    CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection checkedItems = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems;
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.Count; i++)
    {
        checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(checkedItems[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: So what do you want to delete all the checked items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete an item, the `checkedItems` collection gets smaller.  Just remove the first one repeatedly:

```
while (checkedItems.Count > 0)
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(checkedItems[0]);
}
```

Or remove in reverse order:

```
for (int i = checkedItems.Count; i > 0; )
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(checkedItems[--i]);
}
```

Even better, use CheckedIndices, which avoids the need to search for matching items and confusion in the case of duplicates:

```
var checkedItemIndices = checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices;
for (int i = checkedItemIndices.Count; i > 0; )
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(checkedItemIndices[--i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out a few minutes ago and was about to answer it but I don't have enough rep. And yeah that was the solution I used except I didn't think about the > 0 part which makes it simpler. I made a variable to store the original Count and then used it as my 'i < ___' part. So your method is a bit cleaner, thanks!

Comment: Thanks Grant.  I fixed it a different way but your point was valid.